# How to set as wallpaper from a String list/Url

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello guys I'm creating an application of Wallpapers where I'm fetching all the images from Firebase database which are in String format.

Now I'm stuck on Set As Wallpaper because the images are in Url format and the wallpaperManager.setResource(int) only supports int formate.

I have also tried to convert Url to Bitmap but its also not working for me.

```
fabSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String urldisplay = list.get(position).getImageURL();
                    Bitmap bmp = null;

                    try {
                        URL ulrn = new URL(urldisplay);
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ulrn
                                .openConnection();
                        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                        int widthPx = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                                .getWidth();
                        int heightPx = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                                .getHeight();
                        bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, widthPx, heightPx,
                                true);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                    }

                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                            .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        myWallpaperManager
                                .setBitmap(bmp);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(SecondTest2Activity.this, "Wallpaper Successfully Set On Screen ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

I have tried the above code but not worked....may be this question will be duplicate of someone but i have searched a lot on net but didn't find any solution

> I have found the solution

```
String url = list.get(position).getImageURL();
                    ImageView img=new ImageView(SecondTest2Activity.this);
                    Picasso.get().load(url).into(img);
                    Bitmap bitmapImg = ((BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                            .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        myWallpaperManager
                                .setBitmap(bitmapImg);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Why setting bitmap doesnt work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for Android in which you can pass to the `load()` method the `url` which should be of type String. If you are having a list of `Url` objects, then just get the String representation of that objects and use the following line of code:

```
GlideApp
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(yourImageView);
```